# what will be the output of git show for a commit id who has two parents?

Tags: git, merge, show, commit

git show compares commit to its parent commit . but we can merge and and the resultant commit will have two parents .In that case what will be the output if i run git show on that id. which parent will be diff against or if both are chosen how will the output look like?
I am using it like this

```
git show commit_id
#commit_id is the id of a merged commit
```

Answer (score 0):

**Source**

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html

> For commits it shows the log message and textual diff. It also
>   **presents the merge commit in a special format** as produced by git
>   diff-tree --cc.